# Citrix - PB - Email

Tags: powerbuilder, citrix

We are using PB application in two way one is access via Citrix server and another one is standalone.

A PB 11.5 developed application, I am using via Citrix XenApp - Applications - In this PB application we are using functionality, which sends email notifications to our customers without opening compose email. But it refers the outlook profile "Outlook" or "Default Outlook Profile". Sometimes it is not working and sometime it is working. For some of the users couldn't able to email atleast a time from citrix. So I checked particular users profile settings in following //ctxrprof/userid/Application Data/Microsoft/Outlook.

Note: No issues in standalone application, Email notifications are properly sending to customers.

I am new to this Citrix Environment, Please can someone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does every Citrix user already have a defined Outlook profile?

Comment: I think so, But I am not sure about citrix side. But our standalone application has been sending email notification to our customers which is developed from PB 11.5

Comment: That's what I mean, though, they HAVE to have a defined Outlook profile on the Citrix server for it to send email through MAPI.

Comment: "Sometimes it is not working and sometime it is working." Is there any pattern you've discerned? Is it at least consistent within a user session? FWIW, I doubt you'd be able to do this on a Citrix box, but if I had full privileges and a reproducible case, I'd use SysInternal's/MS's Process Monitor to observe a failure case.

Comment: I can be able to reproduce this issue in Test of Citrix server. But I am not very sure where the user's profiles will be there in Citrix server. But my Test standalone application is working fine.

Comment: yes, we have defined outlook profile for example "Default Outlook Profile". But the name is OK in application side. But how can we check the outlook profile name in outlook? Where it will be available? as well as where it will be avaialable in citrix? for HillBilly Developer

Comment: Are you using Oracle? If so use the built in dbms_util package it makes sending mail a breeze compared to MS.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Oracle, sending mail via Oracle is so much easier when you are using Citrix. The mail settings are made on the server via the utl_smtp package in oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mail
(
  sender      IN VARCHAR2,
  recipient   IN VARCHAR2,
  ccrecipient IN VARCHAR2,
  subject     IN VARCHAR2,
  message     IN VARCHAR2
 )  IS

 connection utl_smtp.connection;
 mailhost VARCHAR2(30) := 'displacedguy.com';
 header VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

  -- Start the connection.

  connection := utl_smtp.open_connection(mailhost,25);

  header:= 'Date: '||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss')||UTL_TCP.CRLF||
     'From: '||sender||''||UTL_TCP.CRLF||
  'Subject: '||subject||UTL_TCP.CRLF||
       'To: '||recipient||UTL_TCP.CRLF||
       'CC: '||ccrecipient;

  -- Handshake with the SMTP server

  utl_smtp.helo(connection, mailhost);
  utl_smtp.mail(connection, sender);
  utl_smtp.rcpt(connection, recipient);
  utl_smtp.rcpt(connection, ccrecipient);
  utl_smtp.open_data(connection);

  -- Write the header

  utl_smtp.write_data(connection, header);

  utl_smtp.write_data(connection, UTL_TCP.CRLF ||message);
  utl_smtp.close_data(connection);
  utl_smtp.quit(connection);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_SMTP.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(' Invalid Operation(s) in SMTP transaction.');
  WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(' Problems sending email try again later.');
  WHEN UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(' Error(s) in SMTP transaction.');   
END;
```

To use in PowerBuilder create a generic transaction object if you don't have one already and add RPCFUNC definition for your utl_smtp package and give it an alias friendly name. Once defined you can call the package function by using sqlca.sendmail(a, b, c, d); You can call it like a function.

This isn't really an answer but a workaround for those using Oracle. Thought it was worth mentioning.